# How to automate a Kendo UI dropdown using selenium webdriver?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

While trying to automate, I am able to access only the first 32 elements in my dropdown, the remaing elements are not getting loaded until I do a scroll inside the dropdown. How to handle this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Scroll down the dropdown with selenium. I think the Kendo UI dropdown supports using arrow down key for that, use `SendKeys` for that.

If that doesn't cause the items to load, you may also need to trigger JavaScript change event or some other function. See `JavaScriptExecutor` for that.